# Can't Find Mongoose Model Model Expreesjs4

Tags: express, mongoose, mlab

I am trying to follow a tutorial's model example, but I am running into an issue when trying to export my model module. It says that my schema is not defined, but the schema variable is declared in the file. Is this issue more related to my mongoose database connection in the server.js file? Any help would be great. thanks.

Error:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/beerlocker/models/beer.js:9

module.exports = mongoose.model('Beer', BeerSchema);

                                        ^

ReferenceError: BeerSchema is not defined

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/beerlocker/models/beer.js:9:41)

    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

    at require (module.js:380:17)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/beerlocker/server.js:6:12)

    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

beer.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var BeerShcema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    quantity: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Beer', BeerSchema);
```

server.js

```
// Get the packages we need
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Beer = require('./models/beer');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pw@ds04xxxx.mongolab.com:4xxxx/beerlocker')

// Create our Express application
var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser());

// Use environment defined port or 3000
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Create our Express router
var router = express.Router();

// Initial dummy route for testing
// http://localhost:3000/api
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'You are running dangerously low on beer!' });
});

var beersRoute = router.route('/beers');

beersRoute.post(function(req, res) {
    var beer = new Beer();

    beer.name = req.body.name;
    beer.type = req.body.type;
    beer.quantity = req.body.quantity;

    beer.save(function(err){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Beer was added'});
    });
});

// Register all our routes with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Insert beer on port ' + port);
```

Comment: `BeerShcema != BeerSchema`

Comment: Wow! Pretty big slip up. Haha. Thanks @JohnnyHK

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve all of my issues. New Error:

`/Users/connorphillips/Desktop/Projects/node/beerlocker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:245
        throw message;      
              ^
MongoError: auth fails
 It looks like a mongo error. Any idea what is causing it?`

Comment: @cphill if it's an auth error you're not using the correct mongolab credentials. please reach out to us at support@mongolab.com if you need help!